# How to compile an official VS1003 / VS1053 example for Arduino / ESP8266?

Tags: c++, esp8266, c, compile

Have anyone ever successfully run any of the [official playback and recording examples](http://www.vlsi.fi/en/support/software/microcontrollersoftware.html) for **VS1003** or **VS1053** on Arduino / ESP8266? I mean, I was able to play sound with VS1003, but I just can't make the official example compile on Arduino IDE... It looks like it should be no problem (just provide a few methods and copy the main method code from the PDF file to the `setup()` in sketch) but I'm just getting a bunch of stupid compiler or linker errors, like "undefined reference to 'VSTestInitHardware()' " while the player.h header file (containing it) is included. I'm not a C / C++ expert so it's either something stupid I do or it's just not possible on Arduino. Can anyone provide a compilable example? I'm trying it with [ESP8266](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino) currently (and it is my desired target CPU), but an Arduino Uno version could help too (it throws different errors but doesn't compile neither). Thank you.

Comment: The Arduino IDE should only be used to build Arduino code.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams They say (in their examples) that their code is plain C and it can be compiled for ANY microcontroller - you just have to supply the device-specific methods. That is exactly what I'm trying to (and can't) do.

Comment: You can't compile plain C in the Arduino IDE, only Arduino code.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I would qualify that as "you can't compile it **unmodified**". And if all he's using is library routines, wrapping them in extern "C" {} should do the trick.

Comment: @JayEye: Can you explain in detail what trick do you mean, please? I was trying making the header file's methods `extern` but it didn't help. I can live with modifying a little the examples - just don't want to rewrite them in different way, especially I want to test more than one chip version, so I would have to change them all separately.

Comment: adding this as answer so I can format properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after long battle with C++ compiler I have a **working example** (at least for VS1003 and ESP8266) with a checklist how to recreate it (with minimal changes to the example files). I'm sure someone else will have this problem so I'm attaching it:

**The things that you need to do in player1003.c**:

- rename to player1003.h (change file extension only)
- remove all 5 includes from the top (stdio, string, stdlib, ctype, "player.h")
- turn off `REPORT_ON_SCREEN` (change `#if 1` to `#if 0`) if you don't want to have a lot of serial output
- mass replace "FILE *" to "File " - mind the space (change type of file variables in all methods, mark "Case sensitive" to avoid errors in player1053!)
- mass replace `fopen(` to `fopen2(`
- mass replace `printf(` to `Serial.printf(`
- mass replace `fflush(stdout);` to `//fflush(stdout);` (or `Serial.flush();`)
- remove method: `VSTestInitHardware(void)`
- remove `SM_SDISHARE` flag from `WriteSci(SCI_MODE, SM_SDINEW|SM_SDISHARE|SM_TESTS|SM_RESET);` line  (in `VSTestInitSoftware(void)` method)
- in `VSTestHandleFile()` at the bottom add `fp.close();` after `VS1003PlayFile(fp);` and `VS1003RecordFile(fp);` lines (especially after the record!). We don't want unclosed files on SD card.

**The main sketch (.ino):**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include "player.h"

using namespace std;


// I use these values below for ESP-12 (ESP8266):
#define MP3_xCS 2
#define MP3_xDCS 4
#define MP3_DREQ 5
#define MP3_xRESET 16
#define SD_CS 15
#define SPI_MOSI 11 //SPI
#define SPI_MISO 12 //SPI
#define SPI_CLK  13 //SPI


#define  WAIT_DREQ()  while(!digitalRead(MP3_DREQ))


File song;


int VSTestInitHardware()
{
  pinMode(MP3_DREQ, INPUT);
  pinMode(MP3_xCS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MP3_xDCS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MP3_xRESET, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SD_CS, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(MP3_xCS, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(MP3_xDCS, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(MP3_xRESET, LOW); // chip off!
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(MP3_xRESET, HIGH); // chip on!

  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!SD.begin(SD_CS))
  {
    Serial.println("Can't initialize SD!");
    return -1;
  }
  Serial.println("SD OK!");

  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV32);  // Bus SPI at 1MHz (for Arduino: 16MHz / 16 = 1MHz)
  SPI.transfer(0xFF);  // Write something to the bus
  delay(10);
  return 0;
}


void setup()
{
  if (VSTestInitHardware() || VSTestInitSoftware())
  {
    Serial.printf("Failed initializing VS10xx, exiting\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  /* ... */
  /* Playback example. You can call these functions many times in a row
  because they leave VS1003 in a stable state. */
  VSTestHandleFile("TEST.mp3", 0);  // remember to use 8.3 file names format on SD!
  /* Recording example */
  VSTestHandleFile("RECORDED.WAV", 1);  // original example for VS1003 has a bug here (OGG extension)

  Serial.println("Playing recorded file...");
  VSTestHandleFile("RECORDED.WAV", 0);

  Serial.println("THE END");
}

void loop()
{
}



void WriteSci(unsigned char reg, unsigned char hsb, unsigned char lsb)
{
  // for debugging:
  Serial.printf("Setting %s to: %d (%X, %X)\n", RegName(reg), (hsb<<8) + lsb, hsb, lsb);

  WAIT_DREQ();
  digitalWrite(MP3_xCS, LOW);

  SPI.transfer(0x02);
  SPI.transfer(reg);
  SPI.transfer(hsb);
  SPI.transfer(lsb);
  WAIT_DREQ();
  digitalWrite(MP3_xCS, HIGH); 
}


void WriteSci(u_int8 addr, u_int16 data)
{
  WriteSci(addr, data >> 8, data & 255);
}


uint16_t ReadSci (unsigned char reg)
{
  WAIT_DREQ();
  digitalWrite(MP3_xCS, LOW);

  SPI.transfer(0x03);
  SPI.transfer(reg);
  delayMicroseconds(10);

  char response1 = SPI.transfer(0xFF);
  WAIT_DREQ();
  char response2 = SPI.transfer(0xFF);
  WAIT_DREQ();

  digitalWrite(MP3_xCS, HIGH);

  unsigned int resultvalue = response1 << 8;
  resultvalue |= response2;

  // for debugging:
  if (reg != SCI_HDAT0 && reg != SCI_HDAT1)  // these registers are filtered out because they are intensively used during recording
    Serial.printf("%s is: %d (%X, %X)\n", RegName(reg), resultvalue, resultvalue >> 8, resultvalue & 255);

  return resultvalue;
}


int WriteSdi(const u_int8 *data, u_int8 bytes)
{
  WAIT_DREQ();
  digitalWrite(MP3_xDCS, LOW);

  for(int y = 0 ; y < bytes ; y++)
    SPI.transfer(data[y]);

  digitalWrite(MP3_xDCS, HIGH);
}


const char* RegName(uint8_t reg)
{
  switch (reg)
  {
    case 0x00: return "SCI_MODE";
    case 0x01: return "SCI_STATUS";
    case 0x02: return "SCI_BASS";
    case 0x03: return "SCI_CLOCKF";
    case 0x04: return "SCI_DECODE_TIME";
    case 0x05: return "SCI_AUDATA";
    case 0x06: return "SCI_WRAM";
    case 0x07: return "SCI_WRAMADDR";
    case 0x08: return "SCI_HDAT0";
    case 0x09: return "SCI_HDAT1";
    case 0x0A: return "SCI_AIADDR";
    case 0x0B: return "SCI_MIXERVOL";
    case 0x0C: return "SCI_AICTRL0";
    case 0x0D: return "SCI_AICTRL1";
    case 0x0E: return "SCI_AICTRL2";
    case 0x0F: return "SCI_AICTRL3";
  }
}


void SaveUIState(void)
{
}

void RestoreUIState(void)
{
}

int GetUICommand(void)
{
  while (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char c = Serial.read();
    if (c != 10 && c != 13)
      return c;
  }
  return -1;
}


void exit(int code)
{
  if (code == EXIT_SUCCESS)
    Serial.println("Exited with no error.");
  else
    Serial.printf("Terminated with error: %d\n", code);
  while (true) { yield(); }  // yield() is needed for ESP8266 only
}


File fopen2(const char* fileName, const char* mode)
{
  if (mode[0] == 'w')  // fast workaround!
  {
    Serial.printf("Opening for writing: %s\n", fileName);
    song = SD.open(fileName, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.printf("Opening for reading: %s\n", fileName);
    song = SD.open(fileName, O_RDONLY);
  }

  if (!(song)) 
  {
     Serial.printf("File not found: %s\n", fileName);
     return song;
  }
  Serial.printf("File opened: %s\n", fileName);
  return song;
}

size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, File stream )
{
  yield();  // this is needed for ESP8266 only (otherwise reboots)
  return stream.read(ptr, size * count);
}

int fseek ( File stream, long int offset, int origin )
{
  stream.seek(offset);
}

size_t fwrite ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, File stream )
{
  return stream.write((uint8_t*)ptr, size * count);
}

int fflush ( File stream )
{
  stream.flush();
  return 0;
}


#include "player1003.h"
```

(i had to manually clean this file out of my additional code, but I hope it will compile just fine).

**I have a request:**

If you run this example, please write me in comment whether the recording worked. I can't make my VS1003 module record sound. I have a suspicion that mic in my module is broken. That's why I was trying the official example (with the minimum changes as possible). It records only noise in my case, but plays mp3 perfectly. If you have a working example of recording, please share too.

And one more to the people with more rep (moderators): Please add a `VS1003` (and `VS1053` and `VS1063`) keywords and assign it to my questions about VS1003, because I'm unable to do it and it should be done. The chip deserves a keyword. (It's really good and not expensive.)

Answer (score 0):

This is best given with an example.

`foo.h` contains:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern int foo(const char* s);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`foo.c` contains:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(const char* s) {
  printf("foo: %s\n", s);
  return 42;
}
```

So first, let's create a "library" from foo.c. Since we are compiling with a C, not a C++ compiler, the stuff in `#ifdef __cplusplus` is ignored.

```
$ gcc -c foo.c
```

This creates a file called `foo.o`, which we can then use to link with.

`as24823.cpp` contains:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int f = foo("called");
  std::cout << f << std::endl;
}
```

Now I can compile the C++ program (as24823.cpp) and use a C library (foo.c):

```
$ g++ -c ase24823.cpp
$ g++ ase24823.o foo.o
$ ./a.out
foo: called
42
```

*Why is this necessary?*, I hear you ask. Well, for reasons that are way beyond the scope of this posting, C++ mangles entry point names. Observe:

```
$ nm as24823.o
$ nm ase24823.o 
...
                 U foo    
0000000000000000 T main
...
```

(I've removed most of the output). What this is telling me is that the .o file has an *entry point* called "main", and an *undefined external reference* (something that will be provided by a library) called "foo". Now, if I remove the ifdefs from the foo.h file and recompile, this is what I get:

```
$ cat foo.h
extern int foo(const char* s);
$ g++ -c ase24823.cpp 
$ nm ase24823.o 
0000000000000000 T main
                 U _Z3fooPKc
....
```

What just happened? Because C++ no longer knows that it's supposed to call a *C* function, it has mangled the external so as to encode the types of its arguments (this is so that overloading can happen).

If you find this confusing, don't worry -- just edit the .h files that come with your C libraries and you'll be fine.